# Threaded=true Flask larger application file structure

Tags: python, flask

I recently created a web app and used the suggested file structuring from flask for separating views in different files. see here, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/.

But I also need to have the threaded parameter set to true which I would usually do at app.run(threaded=True) stage of testing. But I now run the app a different way, i tried putting "threaded=True" into my setup.py and that didn't do anything and was wondering how to get this working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tell the `flask run` command to use threads:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=yourapplication
$ flask run --with-threads
```

Don't put this decision in your code; it is up to your WSGI server to run with threads or not.

You can see what options `flask run` accepts with `flask run --help`.